# Prime faces on top of myfaces 2.1.7

Tags: jsf, primefaces, netweaver

I'm looking for additional JSF functionality in my SAP NetWeaver environment 7.3, Prime Faces was our first choice.

However, I've integrated Prime Faces 3.5 on top of MyFaces (myfaces-api-2.1.7.jar & myfaces-impl-2.1.7.jar) but when deploying my corresponding EAR, an error returned stating:

`[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContextFactory is no javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextFactory]`.

At this point, I ran out of options and I'm desperately hoping someone to come up with a small clue.

Thanks in advance,

Wesley

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to define a new *reference-target* in application-j2ee-engine.xml towards the already running myfaces libraries instead of having them declared as a new library dependency (SAP NWDS - Component Properties - Dependencies).